# How to use a library on global object (without importing it) from a TypeScript module?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, ramda.js

I am writing a userscript which have dependencies injected by a userscript addon. I **must not import** any library, I want just the types. JS code before adding TS was working.

Example:

```
R.range(0, 3)
```

crashes TypeScript compiler on

```
'R' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

I tried

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/ramda/index.d.ts"/>
```

which didn't work - compiler still refusing working code.

I also tried to add it to the `externals` in webpack config while using `import` statements. That didn't work:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
```

Just importing type doesn't work:

```
import type R from 'ramda';
```

->

```
TS1361: 'R' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'.
```

I also tried putting it onto global object manually:

```
import type R from 'ramda';

declare global {
  // neither working
  const R = R;
  const R: R;
}
```

---

So, my questions are:

**Why it's not working with Ramda while jQuery works fine (global variable without import)?**

**How to "import" just types of Ramda, the global `R` variable, without importing (bundling) source code of a whole library?**

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, that namespace thing got me confused...

Put

```
import type R from 'ramda';

declare global {
  const R: typeof R;
}
```

in `ramda.d.ts` and `R` should be accessible from everywhere.